# fast computation of matrix trace norm in R

Tags: r, matrix, eigenvalue

I have a square symmetric real matrix `S` of dimension 31.  I want to compute its trace (nuclear) norm, Frobenius (Hilbert--Schmidt) norm and operator (spectral) norm.  I am using `eigen`:

```
x <- eigen(S, only.values = TRUE)$values
sum(abs(x))
sqrt(sum(x^2))
max(abs(x))
```

Is there a faster way to do this?  For the Frobenius norm, I suppose that `sum(S^2)` should be faster.  I also believe that there should be a way to compute the operator norm faster, as it only requires the maximal and minimal eigenvalues rather than all of them.  I am not sure, however, how to handle the trace norm efficiently.  It can be computed as the trace of the matrix square root of `t(S) %*% S` but (at least to my knowledge) computing the matrix square root is done using `eigen` too (see below my code if helpful).

I don't know if it helps at all, but I also know that `S+diag(31)` is positive semidefinite.

I need to do this for a lot of matrices (4 000 000 or so) so even mild improvements would be consequential.

Here is the code for matrix square root I am using

```
sqm <- function(A)
{
    A <- eigen(A)
    A$vectors %*% (sqrt(A$values) * t(A$vectors))
}
```

Comment: Maybe function `norm()` can be useful.

Comment: @MarceloFernandoBefumo Thanks, type = "2" gives the operator norm and type = "F" gives Frobenius norm, but I don't think it can give the trace norm.